# Android Spinner add items

Tags: android, button, spinner, addition, items

I'm working on an App and need some help with the spinner widget.
The array has no entries by its creation and will be filled in another function. So I have to use `adapter.add(item);` and `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);` to update the spinner in this function, I guess.

> ```
> // global variables
>     String[] test = new String[100];
>     int x = 0;
>     Spinner s;
>     ArrayAdapter adapter;
>     Button btn1;
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
>         btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
>         btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
>         s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
>         adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
>         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);
>     }
>
>   public void onClick(View arg0) {
>       test[x] = String.valueOf(x);;
>       x++;
>       adapter.add(test[x]);
>       s.setAdapter(adapter);
>   }
> ```

just for education purpose I tried this, but there is still a bug in the onClick() function.
Something has to be done with the ArrayAdapter, I guess. But I don't familiar with this and didn't found an example for adding itmes by pressing a button.
Maybe there is just a simple failure somewhere else, but currently I just don't see it.

here the complete code:

> ```
>     ArrayList<Integer>  test;
>     int x = 0;
>     Spinner s;
>     ArrayAdapter adapter;
>     Button btn1;
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.main);
>         btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
>         btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
>         s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
>         test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
>         adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);
>     }
>
>   public void onClick(View arg0) {
>       test.add(x);
>       x++;
>       s.setAdapter(adapter);
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding x to an array element then passing this element to the adapter.add method. This is effectively the same as using: adapter.add(x);.

Why not use an ArrayList instead of a array. ArrayLists are dynamic, and do not need to be given an initial size.
A very quick check has shown me that there is a constructor for an Array Adapter that is compatible with ArrayLists and I expect any descendant of the List class.  See the code example below.

```
ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);
```

I know this is not a complete solution to your problem, but just a pointer to a possibly better way of doing it.

Do a web search with the terms ‘android updating arrayAdapter at runtime’ and I am sure you will stumble upon a more concrete example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, problem solved.
never used an ArrayList before, actually it seems to my as a very comfortable substitute for an ordinary array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting the `ArrayAdapter`'s data to be a 100 null strings, and then adding to the end of that when you press the button. Try changing your `test` variable to be `new String[0]`.

Then in your `onClick` method, just call `adapter.add(String)`. It will add it to the end of your current data, so you don't need to give it a big enough array initially.

Comment: ok, this makes sense. But it won't work (I tried) just by changing the array to `new String[0]` and adapt the `onClick` function.
There is still an UnsupportetOperationException. 
anyway doesn't matters Andrew S found a better solution (thanks for that).
But thank you for your help.

Comment: Ahh, the add function must only be supported when using a `List`